# How do I fix the formatting of dynamic output in my workflow email message?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I'm sure this is an easy answer, but I can't seem to find it. I'm using SharePoint designer 2013 to generate a customized email message. But I can't get the format right for variables and for links. Here's what the received email looks like:

```
Name: 1;#DOE, 1;#Jane
Role: 23;#Partner Coordination 
<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7urirjhfg784n/DOE%Jane%20Profile.pdf?dl=0">Personal History Form</a>
```

Can you help me know how to remove the variable number semi-colon hash and how to make the formatting of the link work?

I've followed [this tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4), but it seems to not address this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I got it. The `Return field as:` needs to be set to `Lookup Value (as Text)` if it's a `Current Item` variable and needs to be set to `As String` if it's a `Workflow` variable.

[image]

and the links need to be inserted with the hyperlink icon.

[image]